# How does Linux kernel compare to microkernel architectures?

Tags: linux, kernel

I read once that one advantage of a microkernel architecture is that you can stop/start essential services like networking and filesystems, without needing to restart the whole system. But considering that Linux kernel nowadays (was it always the case?) offers the option to use modules to achieve the same effect, what are the (remaining) advantages of a microkernel?

Comment: On the topic of microkernels and Linux, see also [this very good answer to “Why linux is called monolithic kernel”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806585/why-linux-is-called-monolithic-kernel/1806597#1806597).

Comment: You can read debate on MicroKernel vs Monolithic kernel. http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/opensources/book/appa.html In this paper, Andrew Tanenbaum supports Microkernel and Linus Torvalds supports Monolithic kernel.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Microkernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) require less code to be run in the innermost, most trusted mode than [monolithic kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernels). This has many aspects, such as:

- Microkernels allow non-fundamental features (such as drivers for hardware that is not connected or not in use) to be loaded and unloaded at will. This is mostly achievable on Linux, through modules.
- Microkernels are more robust: if a non-kernel component crashes, it won't take the whole system with it. A buggy filesystem or device driver can crash a Linux system. Linux doesn't have any way to mitigate these problems other than coding practices and testing.
- Microkernels have a smaller [trusted computing base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base). So even a malicious device driver or filesystem cannot take control of the whole system (for example a driver of dubious origin for your latest USB gadget wouldn't be able to read your hard disk).
- A consequence of the previous point is that ordinary users can load their own components that would be kernel components in a monolithic kernel.

Unix GUIs are provided via X window, which is userland code (except for (part of) the video device driver). Many modern unices allow ordinary users to load filesystem drivers through [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). Some of the Linux network packet filtering can be done in userland. However, device drivers, schedulers, memory managers, and most networking protocols are still kernel-only.

A classic (if dated) read about Linux and microkernels is the [Tanenbaum–Torvalds debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanenbaum%E2%80%93Torvalds_debate). Twenty years later, one could say that Linux is very very slowly moving towards a microkernel structure (loadable modules appeared early on, FUSE is more recent), but there is still a long way to go.

Another thing that has changed is the increased relevance of [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) on desktop and high-end embedded computers: for some purposes, the relevant distinction is not between the kernel and userland but between the [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) and the guest OSes.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd-paper.html

Comment: That is all very nice theory. If a device gets wedged somehow, the system is toast. If a driver crashes halfway though an operation, no restarting the driver will restore the system to functional state. If you want any performance at all, the drivers must be multithreaded... and the advantage of "one scheduler" is completely lost. Want performance, you have to avoid (increasingly costly) memory copies and context switches... and the "modularity" is lost. Look up sizes of some microkernels, and you'll see they comparable size and complexity to monolithic kernels *with the drivers included*.

Answer (score 16):

A microkernel limits the time the system is in kernel mode, as opposed to userspace, to the absolute minimum possible.

If a crash happens in kernel mode, the entire kernel goes down, and that means the entire system goes down.  If a crash happens in user mode, just that process goes down.  Linux is robust in this regard, but it's still possible for any kernel subsystem to write over the memory of any other kernel subsystem, either purposefully or accidentally.

The microkernel concept puts a lot of stuff that is traditionally kernel mode, such as networking and device drivers, in userspace.  Since the microkernel isn't really responsible for a lot, that also means it can be simpler and more reliable.  Think of the way the IP protocol, by being simple and stupid, really leads to robust networks by pushing complexity to the edges and leaving the core lean and mean.

Answer (score 5):

You should read the other side of the issue:

[Extreme High Performance Computing or Why Microkernels suck](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2007/ols2007v1-pages-251-262.pdf)

[The File System Belongs In The Kernel](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.2864)

Comment: Thanks for posting the links to reading material!
Brent W's point in abstract is sound, and to some degree, I empathize with Christoph L's concern about over-complexity in microkernel synchronization mechanisms; however, I think the latter paper may be overlooking message-based event loops. Since event loops do not share memory with each other, the lock isn't needed, and since (IMO) they lend themselves to a declarative coding style, a consistent algorithm can be _explicitly_ defined (the point of lambda calculus...)
- I usually code apps, but this Q has been an enjoyable learning experience

Answer (score 2):

1. Monolithic kernel is much **older than microkernel**. It’s used in Unix while the idea of microkernel appeared at the end of the **1980's**.
2. Examples of OSes having the monolithic kernels are **UNIX, LINUX** while the OSes having microkernel are **QNX, L4, HURD** and initially **Mach** (not MacOS X) which was later converted into hybrid kernel. Even **MINIX** is not a pure microkernel because its device drivers are compiled as part of the kernel.
3. Monolithic kernels are **faster than microkernels**. The first Mach microkernel is 50% slower than monolithic kernels. Later versions like L4 are only **2% or 4% slower than the monolithic kernel**.
4. Monolithic kernels are generally **bulky** while pure microkernel has to be **small in size**, even fit into the processor's first level cache (first generation microkernel).
5. In monolithic kernels, device drivers reside in the **kernel space** while in the microkernel device drivers reside in the **user space**.
6. Since device drivers reside in the kernel space, it makes monolithic kernel **less secure** than microkernel (Failure in the driver may lead to crash). Microkernels are **more secure** than monolithic kernels, hence they're used in many military devices.
7. Monolithic kernels use **signals and sockets** to ensure IPC while  microkernel approach uses **message queues**. The 1<sup>st</sup> gen of microkernel poorly implemented IPC so they were slow on context switches.
8. Adding new features to a monolithic system means **recompiling the whole kernel** while you can add new feature or patches **without recompiling**

Comment: In (4), you are comparing apples and watermelons. The microkernel itself (by design) contains only minimal functionality, the monolithic kernel contains much more. (6) is a nice theory, it depends on how competently the pieces are developed, and how leaky the *real* IPC mechanism is (for performance, it can't be real "message passing").  Note (7) means a *very* complex handling of "message queues", thus mostly negating their advantages. For (8), in case of e.g. Linux it is certainly possible to compile a module independent of the kernel. This is routinely done for driver development, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at x86 architecture -- monolithic kernel only uses [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(computer_security)) 0 and 3. A waste, really. But than again it can be faster, because of less context switching.

[image: x86 rings]

Comment: The x86 ring structure is just overengineering. No practical use (except virtual machines, but that is increasingly used...)

Answer (score 0):

Windows NT (the underlying kernel to current Windows systems) started out as a quite vanilla microkernel design. Due to performance problems, more and more of the "userland" code migrated into the "micokernel"... today it's microkernel structure is vestigial.

Answer (score -1):

The case is that linux kernel is a hybrid of monolithic and microkernel.
In a pure monolithic implementation there are no modules loading at runtime.

Comment: it's not. the fact that modules are loaded dynamically does not change the fact, that they are run with full kernel privileges, and as part of monolithic kernel.

Comment: For hybrid design it would be more important wheather some drivers (for USB, Scanners, Printers and graphics) are implemented in userspace rather then kernel. The distinction is not clear and Linux can be stated as hybrid kernel as there is libusb, sane, cups and mesa - not because there is insmod and rmmod.

Answer (score -1):

The terms `monolithic kernel`and `microkernel` cannot be seriously compared as they describe different aspects of kernel design (structure vs. size).

A typical monolithic kernel was the SunOS-4.x kernel and Linux is still similar, as you manually configure the content of the basic kernel.

The Solaris kernel (starting with 2.1 on 1992) cannot be called monolithic anymore as all drivers are loaded automatically on demand and only a tiny part is loaded during the initial boot.

SunOS-4.x and Solaris (SunOS-5.x) and Linux are all single context implementations. Their entire code runs in a single MMU context.

Mac OS X is based on Mach and runs as a multi context implementation with several processes separated by MMU contexts. In this concept, drivers are in separate processes and separate MMU contexts.

Many people call Mac OS X a "microkernel system", but it may be that the basic kernel is not smaller than the basic kernel from Solaris.

So it seems that it would be better to talk about `single context kernels` vs. `multi context kernels`.

Comment: MacOS runs an (essentially monolitic) BSD shim over a microkernel. No separation into separate processes at all there, not a *real* microkernel design.

Comment: So you admit a design that uses at least two so called kernel processes. The term  `microkernel` is wrong anyway as it is typically used for something that should be called `multi context kernel`.