# What requirements must a computer program meet to be considered as part to the unix toolkit?

Tags: utilities, unix-philosophy

It is stated [here](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/coping-with-unix/node145.html) that:

> The Unix operating system introduced the idea of a toolkit. That is, rather than having a few generalized and complex utilities programs, the system contains a toolkit of small and simple programs which the user combines to perform sophisticated tasks and to create custom programs.

The author continues with an example where it mentions `cut`, `egrep` and `wc` utilities.

So my question is:

"What requirements must a computer program meet to be considered as part to the unix toolkit?".

EDIT:

As stated in @Jesse_b's answer the POSIX standard defines a list of [standard utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html). This list may change in the future. I would like to know what are the requirements that a utility must cope to be admited in such list.

Comment: Be written in the 1970s? And useful.

Comment: @Jesse_b According to that criteria (being written in the 1970s) a tool like [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) would not be considered as part of the toolkit. Do you agree?

Comment: It certainly is not a standard tool.  I'm not sure if it's being shipped with any distributions but it's certainly not on any of the ones I use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes an operating system "Unix-Like"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87686/what-makes-an-operating-system-unix-like)

Comment: @ThomasDickey My question is more focused on the understanding of the unix toolkit concept. For instance the list of standard utilities mentioned in Jesse_b answer may  be changes in the future with the addition of new utilities. I would like to know what are the requirements that a utility must cope to be admited in such list.

Comment: Then all you'll get is opinion, which makes this closable in any case.

Comment: @Jesse_b it’s in Debian, Fedora, Gentoo and Arch Linux at least ;-). (I don’t know what distros you use...)

Comment: @StephenKitt: Solaris, SmartOS, Centos, RHEL, and macos

Comment: Notice that that [list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) includes optional and deprecated commands -- some of which quite obscure: will the [asa](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/asa.html) users please stand up?

Answer (score 3):

This question is kind of broad and possibly opinionated but POSIX is sort of the defacto standard here and they define a list of [standard utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html).