# Are driver modules loaded and unloaded automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-modules

On Ubuntu 14.04, I found that when I don't plug in my external wireless adapter, its module `rt2800usb` is still shown in `lsmod`.

1. when does  automatically loading a driver module happen? Is it when the device is connected to the computer, or when the OS boots?
2. when does automatically unloading a driver module happen? Is it when the device is disconnected to the computer, or when the OS shuts down?

Answer (score 15):

When the kernel detects a new device, it runs the program [`modprobe`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) and passes it a name that identifies the device. Most devices are identified through registered numbers for a vendor and model, e.g. [PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) or [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) identifiers. The `modprobe` program consults the module alias table `/lib/modules/VERSION/modules.alias` to find the name of the file that contains the driver for that particular device. A similar principle applies to drivers for things that are not hardware devices, such as filesystems and cryptographic algorithms. For more details, see [Debian does not detect serial PCI card after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43699/debian-does-not-detect-serial-pci-card-after-reboot/43723#43723)

Once modprobe has identified which module file (`.ko`) contains the requested driver, it loads the module file into the kernel: the module code is [dynamically loaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) into the kernel. If the module is loaded successfully, it will then appear in the listing from `lsmod`.

The automatic loading of modules happen when the kernel detects new hotpluggable hardware, e.g. when you connect a USB peripheral. The operating system also does a pass of enumerating all the hardware that's present on the system early during startup, in order to load drivers for peripherals that are present at boot time.

It's also possible to manually request the loading of a module with the `modprobe` or `insmod` command. Most distributions include a startup script that loads the modules listed in `/etc/modules`. Another way for modules to be loaded is if they're a dependency of a module: if module A depends on module B, then `modprobe A` loads B before loading A.

Once a module is loaded, it remains loaded until explicitly unloaded, even if all devices using that driver have been disconnected. A long time ago, there was a mechanism to automatically unload unused modules, but it was removed, if I remember correctly, when udev came onto the scene. I suspect that automatic module unloading is not a common feature because the systems that would tend to need it are mostly desktop PCs that have lots of memory anyway (on the scale of driver code).

Comment: Thanks. I haven't modified `/etc/modules`. `rt2800usb` is in the output of `lsmod`, and does that mean that I  connected its device to my computer before since booting?

Comment: @Tim If the module is loaded, and you didn't load it explicitly, and it isn't listed in `/etc/modules`, then yes, presumably the reason the module is loaded is because the device was present at some point.

Comment: `The operating system also does a pass of enumerating all the hardware that's present on the system early during startup` - How exactly is this done? What does the init script invoke to achieve this?

Comment: @AxelFontaine I think it's `udevadm trigger` on a sysvinit system, and I guess that or some equivalent with systemd.

Answer (score 5):

Modules are loaded when the system boots via the [Initial RAM Disk a.k.a the initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd).  The Rationale Section states:

> Many Linux distributions ship a single, generic Linux kernel image –
>   one that the distribution's developers create specifically to boot on
>   a wide variety of hardware. The device drivers for this generic kernel
>   image are included as loadable kernel modules because statically
>   compiling many drivers into one kernel causes the kernel image to be
>   much larger, perhaps too large to boot on computers with limited
>   memory. This then raises the problem of detecting and loading the
>   modules necessary to mount the root file system at boot time, or for
>   that matter, deducing where or what the root file system is.

Ubuntu like many other distributions, chooses to load every device driver into this initrd, regardless of whether the driver is needed or not, and also regardless if the device is present on the system or not. As Giles pointed out, the whole thing is loaded into RAM, and then the used modules are detected at startup, and the unused ones are removed from RAM. Using this approach ensures that Ubuntu will always start on any system regardless of setup. Ubuntu is mimicking a monolithic kernel using microkernel constructs.  See [The Reason This Works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6409/how-does-linux-kernel-compare-to-microkernel-architectures)

---

1. The module `rt2800usb` will always be loaded at bootup because the module was included in the [initramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) that Gilles referred to. The initramfs is a successor of the initrd, therefore it will always be shown by `lsmod`.  Note that you can insert a newly compiled module into the kernel by using `modprobe` followed by the module name.

As a test reboot your system with your wireless adapter unplugged.  If all goes well the module will not be listed in `lsmod`s output because during bootup the detection process started by the initramfs and the init sstem did not find the device during probing, and the module was removed from RAM.

2. To remove a module while a system is running, you can use commands such as `rmmod`, or `modprobe -r` followed by the module name.  At the next boot the module will be reloaded.  See Above.  In most cases a module is not removed dynamically, as this would disable hotplugging, i.e once a module is removed the device using it cannot be detected again when replugged in.

In order to remove a module from `lsmod`, you must remove it from the initramfs image created by recompiling the kernel without the chosen module and then rebuilding the image.  Doing this disables all detection of said module.

Comment: You're confusing loading a file into RAM as part of a RAM disk and loading (i.e. dynamically linking) a module into the running kernel. Modules are loaded temporarily into memory — not into the kernel — from the initrd (technically an initramfs nowadays), but they are then removed from memory after the real root is mounted. Modules are only loaded into the kernel when a device using them is detected (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Whilst I agree here, he was talking about unloading and loading one module which cannot be done unless he chooses to reconfigure the Ubuntu RAM Disk, which is not recommended because Ubuntu chooses to load all the modules into RAM every kernel update. All modules are loaded every time, they are just not all used.

Comment: No, the question is about loading and unloading a module into the kernel. Neither your original answer nor your revised answer addresses that. The initramfs is irrelevant (or at most peripherally relevant) to this question.

Comment: @Gilles Is this better??

Comment: @eyoung100, I agree with Gilles. A discussion of initramfs is not relevant to the question. Modules are generally loaded by enumerating devices in `/sys` and loading the drivers for devices that are actually found in the system. This happens whether the device is present at boot or hot plugged later. `udev` has much more to do with it than initramfs/initrd does, and whether or not all, most, or only some modules are copied into the initramfs (a configuration option in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`) is not especially relevant.

Comment: You're still mixing up loading module files into RAM (irrelevant) with linking modules into the kernel. That makes your answer partly wrong, and confusing in many places even when it's correct.

Comment: @Gilles The OP asked does the module load at bootup or is it removed at disconnect.  Correct??  He wants to know if the module loads at startup, and I'm stipulating that it does via the initrd/initramfs.  The module file is linked/loaded at startup via the detection process, and all of this is loaded into RAM regardless of the wording I use or change.

Comment: You're still mixing up two things that have absolutely nothing to do with each other except that they're sometimes called “loading”: loading a file into memory and linking a module into the running kernel.