# Suppressing auto loading of Linux kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

The answers in [Are driver modules loaded and unloaded automatically?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197688/are-driver-modules-loaded-and-unloaded-automatically) describe how Linux kernel modules are auto loaded at boot based on the hardware in the system.

My question is, can this be short circuited?  In other words, how can I ensure that the auto load doesn't take place for the LKM's I'm writing, so that I can do the loading manually during early testing phase?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your module in the directory under `/lib/modules` where modprobe goes to look for module files.

If there's a module there that would handle this device and you want to skip it in favor of your module, blacklist the module by writing a file [`/etc/modprobe.d/my-blacklist.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/modprobe.d.5.html) (the name can be anything “reasonable” with the `.conf` extension) containing

```
blacklist nameofthemodule
```